# How to get value of selected radio button using JavaScript and then show that value in next page?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I need to get a selected radio button show on the next page. And I don't know to solve this issue can you guys please help me...

Here is my code

**HTML code is**

```
<input type="radio" name="months" value="2500" checked=""> 
<input type="radio" name="months" value="4000" checked="">
<input type="radio" name="months" value="7000" checked="">
 <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()" href="{{ route('checkout') }}">Buy Now</a>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script> 
    function displayRadioValue() { 
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ""; 
        var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 

        for(i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) { 

            if(ele[i].type="radio") { 

                if(ele[i].checked) 
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML 
                            += ele[i].name + " Rs: " 
                            + ele[i].value + "<br>"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Are you opening *the next page* using [Magnific Popup](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup)?

Comment: sir, I need to show the radio button value in next page div

Comment: Then, store that values in session and use them in the next page.

Comment: is any way ??? because it is static values I just need to only show selected values

Comment: Are you using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: No, I'm using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

You should use form

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">>
<input type="radio" name="months" value="2500" checked=""> 
<input type="radio" name="months" value="4000" checked="">
<input type="radio" name="months" value="7000" checked="">
<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" type="button" onclick="displayRadioValue()" href="{{ route('checkout') }}">Buy Now</a>
</form>
```

Comment: sir I need to show radio button value in div how can I do that????